# Combining data from multiple sheets with an identifier from each [Google Apps Script]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Apps Scripts to copy a range of data from one spreadsheet to another. The goal is to combine the results from multiple GA report sheets into one combined sheet. The script I have included below accomplishes part of this goal, but I also need to include an identifier to let me know which GA report each row comes from.

Example below (in reality there are more data columns, but for simplicity):

GA report 1, site = abc

```
data
1
2
3
```

GA report 2, site = xyz

```
data
4
5
6
```

Currently, I can do this:

Combined data

```
data
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

What I need is this:

```
site    data
abc     1
abc     2
abc     3
xyz     4
xyz     5
xyz     6
```

I think, ideally site would come from the tab name but it could also just be hard coded. And order of the columns is not important as long as it is consistent. I can think of at least two potential solutions: add the site to the range before setting the values in the combined sheet or add site to combined sheet after setting the values. But this is where I need help.

Current code:

```
function appendRows() {
//get data from GA report in range
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetData = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var lastColumn = sheetData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = sheetData.getLastRow();
  var rangeR1C1 = "R16C1:R"+lastRow+"C"+lastColumn;
  var range = sheetData.getRange(rangeR1C1);
  var values = range.getValues();

//copy range to combined sheet
  var ssCombined = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx');
  var combinedSheet = ssCombined.getSheets()[0];
  lastRow = combinedSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  combinedSheet.getRange(lastRow,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Edit: another example

```
dataset1     dataset2
1            3
2            4
```

Merged data

```
dataset1      1
dataset1      2
dataset2      3
dataset2      4
```

etc.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about the relationship between `GA report 1, site = abc` and `GA report 2, site = xyz` and your script. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @tanaike I am using the Google Analytics (GA) report add-on to run a report in the spreadsheet. In the example I have 2 spreadsheets, one for site abc and one for site xyz. The script I posted is in each spreadsheet. The script will combine the data from the spreadsheets for both sites, but I need a way to identify which records are from which site in the combined data. Hopefully that helps clarify.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still image your situation. I apologize for my poor English skill. I think that the values can be merged. But I cannot understand where the site name is.

Comment: @tanaike site name can be anything really. Instead of site abc and site xyz, think of it as data set 1 and data set 2. I can merge them, but I also want to add a value to each row of the merged data to indicate if that data is from data set 1 or data set 2.

Comment: I added another examp at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. This is for `another examp`. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You want to achieve the following situation using Google Apps Script.

- From:

  ```
        dataset1     dataset2
        1            3
        2            4
  ```
- To:

  ```
        dataset1      1
        dataset1      2
        dataset2      3
        dataset2      4
  ```

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- At first, all values are retrieved from the sheet. And, the retrieved data is splitted for each column. At this time, the header value is added. And then, the values of each column are merged as an array.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var lastColumn = sheetData.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = sheetData.getLastRow();
var rangeR1C1 = "R16C1:R"+lastRow+"C"+lastColumn;
var range = sheetData.getRange(rangeR1C1);
var values = range.getValues();
```

To:

```
const data = sheetData.getDataRange().getValues();
const [ha, hb] = data.shift();
const v = data.reduce((o, [a, b]) => {
  o.a.push([ha, a]);
  o.b.push([hb, b]);
  return o;
}, {a: [], b: []});
const values = [...v.a, ...v.b];
```

#### Note:

- Please enable V8 at the script editor.
- If you want to achieve the 1st sample situation, please modify above script. In that case, please retrieve the values from each sheet.

#### References:

- [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)